# How to get the list of maximum value for a column for a list of unique key

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nosql

Let's say I have a table on Parse that has two columns: an identifier set by hand and a numeric property.

I need to write a query that gets me the maximum number on the numeric property per each unique identifier. So in the example below:

```
| identifier | value |
----------------------
| 1          | 10    |
| 2          | 5     |
| 1          | 7     |
| 2          | 9     |
```

I would expect the following output:

```
| identifier | value |
----------------------
| 1          | 10    |
| 2          | 9     |
```

Now I know Parse doesn't have anything like Group By statements, so this is probably not doable as a single query.

What alternative would you suggest in this case? I see some solutions, each with serious drawbacks:

- Compose the result from multiple queries. This would require a query that gets the unique list of identifier and then a separate query for each identifier to get the maximum value. This will probably not scale well if the table grows in size. Also the result is not exactly consistent as the DB can change between queries (for my use case slightly stale date is not too bad). This will heavily impact the request quota limit as a single request can now trigger a large number of requests.
- Keep a separate table that keeps track of this result. This table would have a single row for each identifier, containing the max value. For this I would need a beforeSave trigger that updates the second table. From what I've read there is no guarantee that beforeSave triggers are not executed concurrently so it's very tricky to ensure that I don't accidentally insert multiple values for the same identifier. I would probably have to run a background job that removes duplicates.

For my use case I'll need to get the data on an iOS device so network traffic is also an issue.

Comment: How many unique IDs are you dealing with? How big is your table? I can think of 2-3 ways to deal with this problem with a compound query or subqueries, but knowing your set size would help to optimize since Parse limits returns to 1000 items max.

Comment: There will around 30 - 100 unique IDs. I expect to have at most a few hundred entries per unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints, I think your best option is to use CloudCode `afterSave` events. `beforeSave` can cause too much extra slowdown for your users' experience.

You can get around the concurrent triggers problem by querying the max-value table before you change it and deleting any values that exist for that identifier. Something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Yourclass", function(request) {
  var objectToSave = request.object;
  query = new Parse.Query("Maxvaluetableclass");
  query.equalTo("identifier", objectToSave.identifier);
  query.lessThan("value", objectToSave.value);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      //Delete all the objects in the max value table with smaller values
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
         var object = results[i];
         object.destroy();
      }
      var Maxvaluetableclass = Parse.Object.extend("Maxvaluetableclass");
      var maxValueObject = new Maxvaluetableclass();
      maxValueObject.identifier = objectToSave.identifier;
      maxValueObject.value = objectToSave.value;
      maxValueObject.save();
    },
    error: function(error) {
      //All current values are larger, so do nothing
    }
  });
});
```

**UPDATE:** You'll notice that this improved setup is 'self-cleaning' - each time it's run, it removes all the smaller items. This means you don't have to run a background function

Comment: This solves the problem with duplicates in Maxvaluetableclass but I can't see how it can ensure the correct maximum value is saved. If afterSave is triggered by two inserts of a larger value and the second trigger finishes the query before the first trigger finishes the delete then the saved maximum value is simply the last value written.

Comment: Good point. I have updated my answer to make the system 'self-cleaning' - each run of the `afterSave` function will delete smaller values in the max value table, and two concurrent saves should place nice with each other now.

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan Kreager: I don't have 50reps so I am unable to comment previous answers.
Referring to your answer, the OP should consider how frequent would be this aftersave triggered.Because if you have many records, well, each destroy() in the for loop counts as 1 API request.If I understood the pricing correctly at Parse.

https://www.parse.com/plans/faq